# How to import NPM package in JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript, npm, jsfiddle

I would like to use [valid-url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/valid-url) to validate some URLs using JSFiddle so that I can share it later. I tried adding a link to the `index.js` file from Github (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ogt/valid-url/master/index.js) but Fiddle says:

> Github is not a CDN, using it as such will cause issues with loading the file. Do you still with to it?

And obviously when I try to use it, an error is thrown:

> Refused to execute script from [...] because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

So, is there any way to use npm packages in a JSFiddle? Or any workaround to achieve this?

Comment: You can't use code directly from GitHub, but you can include them from rawgit.com. Also, using RequireJS is probably a good idea because you won't be able to use the normal `require(...)` or `import ...` syntax on the web.

Answer (score 33):

Use [unpkg.com](https://unpkg.com/). They allow you to [load any npm module from the browser](https://github.com/unpkg/unpkg) like a CDN.

Answer (score 13):

Using [UNPKG](https://unpkg.com) you can load any file from any package following this pattern

```
https://unpkg.com/:package@:version/:file
```

So, if you add

```
https://unpkg.com/valid-url@1.0.9/
```

Then you'll get [this](https://unpkg.com/browse/valid-url@1.0.9/) (as shown in the next image)

[image: UNPKG npm package in JSFiddle]

If you specify the index.js file

```
https://unpkg.com/valid-url@1.0.9/index.js
```

Then you'll get [this](https://unpkg.com/valid-url@1.0.9/index.js) (as shown in the next image)

[image: JSFiddle with npm packages]

You'll then be able to use it in your fiddles by adding the Resources you want to.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to `import` something from npm on the frontend, you can use https://www.skypack.dev/ which converts npm modules to ES Modules, example:

```html
<script type="module">
  // Use 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/' + 'npm package name' + '@version its optional'
  import random from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/canvas-sketch-util@1.10.0/random'

  console.log('A random number: ', random.range(1,10))
</script>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle using SkyDev to load an npm module](https://jsfiddle.net/0f9t78sz/5/).

There are many cases that https://unpkg.com/ wouldn't handle that https://www.skypack.dev/ can, so I recommend using it whenever it's on the front-end

I wrote a slightly more complete answer here about this:
[How can I use a CommonJS module on JSFiddle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29202426/how-can-i-use-a-commonjs-module-on-jsfiddle/71302802#71302802)