# How to use npm modules in browser? is possible to use them even in local (PC)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, module, npm-install

I'm new to `npm module` and node.js so it is really difficult to me.

I have a js code whit many points and for each one of them I want to get the nearest city.

To do this, in other question ([Reverse geocoding with big array is fastest way? - javascript and performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49494643/reverse-geocoding-with-big-array-is-fastest-way-javascript-and-performance/49542182?noredirect=1#comment86123448_49542182)), a user suggested me to use two **npm modules**,

```
const kdbush = require('kdbush');
const geokdbush = require('geokdbush');

// I've stored the data points as objects to make the values unambiguous
const cities = [
  { name: "Abano Terme (PD)", latitude: 45.3594, longitude: 11.7894 },
  { name: "Abbadia Cerreto (LO)", latitude: 45.3122, longitude: 9.5928 },
  { name: "Abbadia Lariana (LC)", latitude: 45.8992, longitude: 9.3336 },
  { name: "Abbadia San Salvatore (SI)", latitude: 42.8800, longitude: 11.6775 },
  { name: "Abbasanta (OR)", latitude: 40.1250, longitude: 8.8200 }
];

// Create the index over city data ONCE
const index = kdbush(cities, ({ longitude }) => longitude, ({ latitude }) => latitude);

// Get the nearest neighbour in a radius of 50km for a point with latitude 43.7051 and longitude 11.4363
const nearest = geokdbush.around(index, 11.4363, 43.7051, 1, 50);
```

The problem is this is the first time that I approach at this. Besides I'm Italian and don't speak English very well, and in Italian Google there's nothing.

Can you tell me how could I use these modules?

Do I have to install `Node.js` on my server?

Is it possible to use modules on local PC?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`browserify` is the correct direction, but it took me quite some effort to work out the actual solution. I have summarized a [short blog](https://www.bart.com.hk/use-npm-browser-js/) for this, and here are some quick recap:

Say, you want to use `emailjs-mime-parser` and `buffer` npm libraries in your HTML.

1. install everything required

```bsh
npm install -g browserify
npm install emailjs-mime-parser
npm install buffer
```

2. write a simple `main.js` as a wrapper:

```js
var parse = require('emailjs-mime-parser').default
var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer
global.window.parseEmail = parse
global.window.Buffer = Buffer
```

3. compile everything using `browserify`

```bsh
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

4. now, you could use `bundle.js` inside the HTML file.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src='bundle.js'></script>
<script>
console.log(window.parseEmail);
console.log(window.Buffer);
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Found this cool site: https://wzrd.in where you can do all of this in browser w/o installing anything.

Comment: @Neeraj Unfortunately that browserify as a service site no longer works - on github - since april 21 it was reported that it 502s and still is doing that today.

Comment: Downvoted, because it doesn't answer the original question (how do I use modules in browser) but an entirely different question (how do I turn modules into something that isn't modules at all, but can be used in browser).

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski I cannot see the difference between those 2 questions, if you have to do the latter to achieve the former.

Comment: @BitTickler If.

Answer (score 39):

**https://unpkg.com/**

You can pull content from a NPM package using [unpkg.com](https://unpkg.com). If for instance you need to get the Polymer paper-button web component, you can point to: https://unpkg.com/@polymer/paper-button@3.0.1

Comment: Unpkg is a slow cdn. JSDelivr is a slightly better alternative, it also supports github just in case.

Answer (score 27):

Yeah, you can use npm modules directly on the browser.

[Browserify](http://browserify.org/) is an excelent option for that.

Taken straight from their page:

> Browsers don't have the require method defined, but Node.js does. With
>   Browserify you can write code that uses require in the same way that
>   you would use it in Node.

Now your other questions:

> Do I have to install Node.js on my server?

Yes. But you need node just to install browserify and to bundle your javascripts into a single file that you can include directly on the html. So, once you have the bundled file, you can serve it from anywhere without node.

> Is it possible to use modules on local PC ?

Yes! You can do pretty much anything on your local PC. You can use it as a server for development purposes and run a node.js server in it, for example.

Comment: The question is "how do I use npm modules in browser", not "how do I turn npm modules into something that isn't npm modules at all, but can be used in browser".

Comment: uh, okay then 

Answer (score 15):

If your case is 100% frontend, without depending on some server, you can use the ES Modules syntax for that, and combine with the use of https://www.skypack.dev/ which converts the modules in Common JS to ES Modules.

It is important to use the `type="module"` attributes inside the `script` tag to work properly, this service works locally too

```html
<script type="module">
// Use 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/' + 'npm package name' + '@version its optional'
import random from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/canvas-sketch-util@1.10.0/random'

console.log('A random number: ', random.range(1,10))
</script>
```

There are many cases that https://unpkg.com/ wouldn't handle that https://www.skypack.dev/ can, so I recommend using it whenever it's on the front-end

I wrote a slightly more complete answer here about this:
[How can I use a CommonJS module on JSFiddle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29202426/how-can-i-use-a-commonjs-module-on-jsfiddle/71302802#71302802)

Comment: You STILL have to keep track of all modules you use AND generate the HTML snippet with all the required `<script>` tags? There is STILL no solution (as of 2023) where browser can actually download scripts referenced from inside other scripts with the standard `import` syntax? It MUST still be told in advance and exhaustively what it might possibly need, even if it won't need 99% of that for a particular view?

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski I would also like it to be possible, I believe they haven't done this yet because it makes it easier to import scripts anywhere without restrictions, and this makes system intrusions easier (although they can still be done)