# how to bundle npm packages

Tags: npm, webpack

I have to get a bundle of npm package called graphql-request. Just a single file (bundle.js).
I found bundle.js.org but variables are less verbose and make no sense (like var ab, zc)
Is it possible to get a bundle without any compressing and without using webpack?

Comment: this helped me [how to use npm modules in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49562978/how-to-use-npm-modules-in-browser-is-possible-to-use-them-even-in-local-pc)